# How to change the value of a html element in javascript when the element id contains underscores like _item5_xyz?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the value of an html text box using javascript. i tried the .value but it doesn't work. then i change the id with no underscore id and change the value and changed the id back to original one value is same as original value no change.

```
<input id="_item1govt_id" class=" required-entry input-text required-entry input-text required-entry" type="text" value="1" name="address[1][govt_id]" style="display: none;">


echo "<script> function setFunc".$rs['entity_id']."(obj) 
        {


            var e = document.getElementById('_item".$rs['entity_id']."govt_id');
            e.id = 'ape".$rs['entity_id']."';




            e.value = obj.value;

            alert(e.value);

            e.id = '_item".$rs['entity_id']."govt_id';


        }



</script>         "
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Show your HTML and javascript.

Comment: underscore is perfectly valid in ID and shouldn't cause any problems by itself. Something else wrong in your code

Comment: You could also use jQuery http://jquery.com/

Comment: 1. probably a copy paste error. but you started echo (php code) without beginning it with a <?php  after the html tag
2. also why would you change the id of 'e' and then change it back. 
3. can you also show the code from where you are calling this function just to understand what obj is

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `document.getElementById("ID").value = "new value";`

It will work even if your id contains _ or number.

Please check if your id in html amd id you used in javascript matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the html of your text box, then it can be done as follow by using javascript
      `document.getElementById('textbox_id').innerHTML="New text"`;

For more info, juct check the basic [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).
I think it will help you.

Comment: I think .(dot) is the problem, just use the following:
var e = document.getElementById('_item'+$rs['entity_id']+'govt_id');

Comment: + is not the correct concatinator in PHP, note that the OP is echoing out the entire javascript code as a PHP string so . is correct here

Answer (score 0):

Running your code like below worked fine, have you actually called the function anywhere?

```
<input id="_item2govt_id" class=" required-entry input-text required-entry input-text required-entry" type="text" value="1" name="address[1][govt_id]" style="display: none;">
<?php
$rs = array('entity_id' => 2);
echo "<script> function setFunc" . $rs['entity_id'] . "(obj)
        {


            var e = document.getElementById('_item" . $rs['entity_id'] . "govt_id');
            e.id = 'ape" . $rs['entity_id'] . "';




            e.value = obj.value;

            alert(e.value);

            e.id = '_item" . $rs['entity_id'] . "govt_id';


        }
setFunc" . $rs['entity_id'] . "({value:\"test\"});

</script>";
```

Note at the bottom I call the setFunc2() method.

#### Edit

See here for php fiddle working example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7em-jwq

Answer (score -1):

```
         $("#yourTextBoxIdName").val('newValue');
```